# What specific reasons have I recieved a question ban for?

Tags: support, post-ban, help-center, specific-user

I tried asking a question today on Stack Overflow and received the following error:

> You have reached your question limit. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. I read the help center article and it says:
>
> " If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of
> questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at
> very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking
> further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to
> contribute positively."

I have also read the following questions on Meta Stack Exchange. But they don't give specifics. I've tried editing my posts based upon their advise but I now need specifics based upon my previous questions:

[Post 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342579/what-specific-reasons-do-you-recieve-a-question-ban-for)

[Post 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-am-i-getting-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

[Post 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

[Post 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Can I ask what suggests that my questions are making the site worse? I understand that my questions don't have lots of votes. But that's mainly because they are in a small niche. Am I missing something else, as I believe most of my questions are on topic and I've tried editing the others to make them on topic.

I hope you can help me see what I'm doing wrong so that I can improve my questions in the future (if I get the chance to).

Here are some of my questions that have been down voted or not voted on, can anyone tell me specific ways I can improve them?

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614215/how-to-create-a-custom-font-size-in-xaml-using-xamarin-so-that-you-can-change-f)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339647/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-method-into-another-method-in-c-sharp-and-whats-the-be)

[Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301914/how-to-get-net-core-2-1-mvc-web-application-debugged-on-a-remote-server)

Comment: You have 4 deleted questions with a score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/58768914) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/58767429) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/57975316) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/54542403)) (in addition to the one downvoted and closed question that is not deleted).

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for showing these to me. Is it best to undelete them and reword them, or do I just learn from them and move on?

Comment: If you think you can *salvage* them, then it's better to undelete them so that the improved versions could potentially be upvoted in future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay, I'll have a look through them and see if any of them can be changed/improved

Comment: I haven't looked at these posts, but in theory they could also be salvageable and undeleting would only make matters worse as they then are more likely to be downvoted more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're correct. I managed to get out of the ban as someone upvoted my posts this morning. But now I'm back in the Ban as I undeleted one of my posts. All I believe I need is someone to look through my posts and tell me what I'm doing wrong (If I actually am doing anything wrong). I know some of my deleted posts are bad but they were written when I was new to Stackoverflow. I believe all my pen questions to be acceptable

Comment: @RyanGaudion - The one question you undeleted is a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Security Hound. I undeleted it. Edited it and then flagged it as duplicate to my other post. Don't know if this was the best thing to do.

Comment: @RyanGaudion - No; It wasn't; however, this isn't about just one bad question.  It is about a series of bad questions.  One does not get question ban after a single question (unless they are borderline)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Is anyone able to look through my posts and tell me how I can  improve them to make them useful?